# Конкатинация срезов мрт

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения

Кто работал с nibabel. При обработке срезов в 3-х мерном мрт скане,и последующем сохранении как единого снимка возникает проблема, что часть данных теряется.

```py
nifti_inarray = np.array(nifti_inarray, dtype=np.uint16)
nifti_inarray2 = np.array(nifti_inarray2, dtype=np.uint16)
nifti_inarray3 = np.array(nifti_inarray3, dtype=np.uint16)
print(nifti_inarray3.shape)
nifti_inarray3 = np.transpose(nifti_inarray3, transpose_ichemic[0])
nifti_inarray =  np.transpose(nifti_inarray , transpose_ichemic[1])
nifti_inarray2 = np.transpose(nifti_inarray2, transpose_ichemic[2])
image_preproc.append(np.array(nifti_inarray2))
image_preproc.append(np.array(nifti_inarray))
image_preproc.append(np.array(nifti_inarray3))
image_preproc = np.array(image_preproc, dtype=np.uint16)
image_preproc = np.transpose(image_preproc, [1, 2, 3, 0])
image_preproc = image_preproc [:, :, :, 0]
img_res1 = nib.Nifti1Image(image_preproc , affine=img_data_w.affine, header=img_data_w.header)
ni2_concat = nib.funcs.as_closest_canonical(img_res1)
nib.save(ni2_concat, os.path.join(output_folder,'copepenn.nii'))
```

Т.е. появляются черные полосы снизу.

[image: все три среза вместе]

Они появляются из-за того что на одной из осей не правильно выбраны зоны (рис ниже).

[image: Искаженный срез]

При этом на других осях в этом месте всё данные есть. Вопрос как правильно конкатенировать срезы. что бы избавиться от потери данных. Если кто сталкивался с таким, подскажите на примере, как это правильно сделать.